# Transaction API error: Transaction already closed: Could not perform operation

Tags: prisma

Currently experiencing a problem when trying to create reusable functions in a service where I'm passing the database connection to a function.

```
createNote = async (input: CreateSupplementalNoteInput): Promise<CaseFile> => {
const { leadIdentifier, notes, createUserId, actor } = input;

const createNotesAction = async (db, caseId: string) => {
  const ACTION_CODE = "UPDATENOTE";
  const ACTION_TYPE_CODE = "CASEACTION";

  const xref = await db.action_type_action_xref.create({
    data: {
      action_code: ACTION_CODE,
      action_type_code: ACTION_TYPE_CODE,
      create_user_id: createUserId,
      create_utc_timestamp: new Date(),
    },
  });

  const action = await db.action.create({
    data: {
      data: {
        case_guid: caseId,
        action_type_action_xref_guid: xref,
        actor_guid: actor,
        action_date: new Date(),
        create_user_id: createUserId,
        create_utc_timestamp: new Date(),
      },
    }
  })
};

try {
  await this.prisma.$transaction(async (db) => {
    const caseFile = await this.findOneByLeadId(leadIdentifier);

    if (caseFile) {
      const { caseIdentifier } = caseFile;

      const update = { ...caseFile, notes };
      db.case_file.update({
        where: { case_file_guid: caseIdentifier },
        data: {
          note_text: notes,
        },
      }).then(result => { 
        createNotesAction(db, caseIdentifier);
      })

      
    } else {
    }
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log("exception: unable to create supplemental note", error);
  throw new GraphQLError("Exception occurred. See server log for details", {});
}

return Promise.resolve({} as CaseFile);
```

};

When I try and pass the db object into my function this is where I'm running into trouble and the connection closes before I get a chance to actually run that function.

I've tried to both await the promise originally, and have tried using the returned promise, but in both situations the transaction closes. New to working with prisma so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this is happening.